# "Unrecognised selector sent to instance" error when calling allObjects on an NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm attempting to load up entities into my view controller using core data, but I am getting the "unrecognised selector sent to instance" error when I attempt to do so. I have two entities, Routine and Exercise when Routine is the owner of Exercise.

In my view controller I am trying to return the list of Exercises that are associated with a selected Routine.

```swift
let exercises = routine.exercises.allObjects as! [Exercise]
```

However this line is throwing me the error. I'm pretty new to using CoreData so I'm a bit confused as to where this error has come from. My two classes are:

```swift
@objc(Exercise)
public class Exercise: NSManagedObject {

}
extension Exercise {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Exercise> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Exercise>(entityName: "Exercise")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var reps: Int16
    @NSManaged public var sets: Int16
    @NSManaged public var owner: Routine

}
```

```swift
@objc(Routine)
public class Routine: NSManagedObject {

}
extension Routine {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Routine> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Routine>(entityName: "Routine")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var exercises: NSSet

}
```

I've tried looking through different questions on stack overflow but I haven't been able to find anything which solves the error, thanks.

EDIT
print(routine.exercises) outputs

```swift
<Exercise: 0x600001591e00> (entity: Exercise; id: 0xe28fa998e4a16a04 <x-coredata://024220B5-49D9-4D66-B7CB-ADE11BEB9F85/Exercise/p12> ; data: { name = "Incline Bench Press"; owner = "0xe28fa998e4b16a06 <x-coredata://024220B5-49D9-4D66-B7CB-ADE11BEB9F85/Routine/p8>"; reps = 0; sets = 4; })
```

whilst the error message is:

```swift
2019-04-17 13:23:09.069636+0100 MyFitnessApp[6564:25418954] -[Exercise allObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001591e00
2019-04-17 13:23:09.075932+0100 MyFitnessApp[6564:25418954] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Exercise allObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001591e00'
```

Comment: Could you paste the entire error message? It seems to me that the object is not actually a `NSSet`. What does `print(routine.exercises)` output?

Comment: @Sulthan I've edited the question to show the output

Comment: It looks like you send the message to a single instance. If you have recently made some changes to your core data model then you might need to clean your project and rebuild. Do you manually generate your NSManagedObject classes, you might need to re-generate them?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry what do you mean by send the message to a single instance? The only change I made was turning the type of exercises in Routine into an NSSet

Comment: It was only my interpretation of the error message and to point out that the error doesn't make any sense for that code, anyway it was only an observation. It is the rest of my comment that is important.

Comment: You also have to update your core data model. It is not enough to change the type of a property.

Comment: @Sulthan I think that's it, I didn't set the relationship in the core data model as a one to many relationship, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message basically says that `exercises` contains an `Exercise` instance, not a `NSSet` instance.

It's not enough to update the type of a property, the really important part is to update your data model which should be a mirror of the definitions in code.

In this case, you should change `exercises` in your model from a one-to-one relationship to a one-to-many relationship. Migration (or clearing data model) will be needed.

Since the property assignments are done dynamically in Objective-C, without proper type control, it can happen that a property declared with type `NSSet` actually contains an instance of `Exercise`.

Answer (score 1):

Been banging my head against this for a couple of hours now and @Sulthan's answer fixed all of my problems.

In the Inspector menu, select the relationship that you're trying to query for your NSSet and switch the relationship type from 'To One' -> 'To Many'.

'To Many' thanks!